# 2d array,adding it values in a weird pattern

Tags: c#, arrays

i started learning C# and programming a few months ago and have some problems. The idea here is we create a 2 dimensional array (the number of rows / columns are added by the user), the numbers need to be between 1 and 10.

Then when the array is created the number sequence ( 3-5-7-9-11 etc) is started in the first and finishes in the last column. The rest of the numbers in the columns are added via keyboard by the user starting with the first row (ignoring column 1 and the last column cause we have that added).

The questions are :

- What will be the best way to check if the numbers of rows/columns are between 1 and 10? (I was thinking of IF-else but isn't there a better way ?)
- How will i make it so that the number sequence 3-5-7 etc is started in the first and finishes in the last column?
  Yeah i feel lost.

Where i am at the moment :

```
        Console.WriteLine("Add row value of 1-10");
        string s1
        s1 = Console.ReadLine();
        int k = int.Parse(s1);

        Console.WriteLine("Add column value of 1-10");

        string s2;
        s2 = Console.ReadLine();
        int p = int.Parse(s2);
        int[,] M = new int[k, p];
```

Example : we added k(row) & p(coulmn) value of 4.So the array should look like :

3 x x 11

5 x x 13

7 x x 15

9 x x 17

Then the X's should be added again manually without overwriting the existing numbers .The value of the numbers doesnt matter.

Comment: Can you show an example matrix that would be generated using your procedure? I don't think I understand exactly what you're trying to do...

Comment: ditto! please be a little more specific!

Comment: It looks to me like you're just interested in making sure that k  and p  are  in-between 1 and 10  in your question, and the rest is just there for context?

Comment: It seems to me that he wants the odd numbers in one array and the evens in another?  OP, have you looked into using a For or Foreach loop?

Answer (score 0):

So... If I get it right you want to ask user the "length and width" of dynamical 2d array?
To check if entered number is between 1 and 10 there's only 1 method:

```
int [,] M;

if (k >= 1 && k <= 10 && p >= 1 && p <= 10)
{
    M = new int[k,p];
}
```

And better is to do `int.TryParse()` for case if user enters characters there instead of numbers, or else you can easily get an `Exception`.

Filling with numbers:

```
int num = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
{
    M[i,0] = num;
    num+=2;
}

for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
{
    M[i,p] = num;
    num+=2;
}
```

This adds numbers in 1st and last column in each row. After that to fill other cells manually you check every cell thet it is not in firs or last column.
I hope I understood you correctly. Provided code may be simplified, but provided in such way for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks so far , my limited english prevents me explaining as well as i want to :<

Comment: Пиши на русском, чего уж там... =)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(k>0 && k<11 && p>0 && p<11)
{
 int i;
 int M[,] = new int[k,p];
 for (i=0;i<k;i++)
 {
  M[i,0]=i*2+3;
  M[i,p-1]=(i+k)*2+3;
 }
}
```